# Schedule several instances of the same action with cron

Tags: wp-cron

I have a simple cron job set up in wordpress:

```
add_action( 'event_hook', 'do_this_function');
wp_schedule_single_event( time() + 300, 'event_hook', array('testvariable') );
```

I use the function do_this_function() to send an email to a user two weeks after they have done a thing.

However, I realize now that 'event_hook' can only be in the cron job queue ONCE at the same time! I need multiple two week count downs to be running at the same time. I am a bit lost on how this can be done.

What is the workaround to this limitation? The only thing that comes to my mind is:

1 Schedule the "event_hook" to run once per day or so.

2 Call a function that will look at the arguments of the "event_hook" cron job. I would put user emails, time when email must be sent and other info in a multidimensional array

3 Iterate the multidimensional array, send email if two weeks have passed, then delete same information from the cron job array

4 Use a separate function for adding the new information from new users to the cron job array when users trigger need for email in two weeks.

Would this work?

Comment: After some reserach I'm a little desperate. Seems that cron jobs are not meant to be fiddled with after they have been created? 

There are functions like wp_get_scheduled_event, but that function REQUIRES that I know the exact arguments of the job I want to retrieve. 

There are no functions to modify the arguments of a cron job.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, I'm really developing a habit of answering my own questions.

Turns out, you CAN queue multiple instaces for the same hook in WP-cron. The data that WP cron uses to separate the instances is the ARGUMENTS. They cannot be the same, or WP refuses to create the new cron job.

Comment: I think I have the same problem. I am creating a plugin where the user can create several scheduled campaigns, but I don't understand how to make X campaign have a different schedule and all in a single wp cron hook. I have seen a plugin that with only 1 hook schedules different times but I don't know how to do it correctly. Any guide?